# What are cflags?

Tags: compiling, git, smartcard

I have some experience with Gentoo, so I know the compiler meaning of CFLAGS, but when I try to configure https://github.com/OpenSC/pam_pkcs11 :

```
# ./bootstrap&&./configure&&make clean&&make&&make install
...
checking for winscard.h... no
configure: error: winscard.h not found, install pcsc-lite, or use PCSC_CFLAGS=... ./configure
```

I do have pcsc though(repo version):

```
# dpkg -l pcscd
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                   Version                  Architecture             Description
+++-======================================-========================-========================-==================================================================================
ii  pcscd                                  1.8.10-1ubuntu1          amd64                    Middleware to access a smart card using PC/SC (daemon side)
```

I don't want to install pcsc_lite though, because I have had a lot of trouble getting my smartcard reader to work and I don't really want to go through that again. That's why I'm interested in CFLAGS. Is there a way that I can point the `./compile` to pcscd?

Comment: How did you install `pcscd`? unless you installed it from source, setting variables (whether `PCSC_CFLAGS` or the more general `CFLAGS`) on the `./configure` command line won't help, since your system won't have the missing header file anywhere (it is provided by the `libpcsclite-dev` development package).

Comment: @steeldriver I installed from repo and it worked fine thanks. Please submit as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Quoted from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFLAGS)

> CFLAGS are  the name of environment variables or of Makefile variables
>   that can be set to specify additional switches to be passed to a
>   compiler in the process of building computer software.
>
> These variables are usually set inside a Makefile and are then
>   appended to the command line when the compiler is invoked. If they are
>   not specified in the Makefile, then they will be read from the
>   environment, if present.

you can easily install it from repository not from source code

```
sudo apt-get install libpcsclite-dev
```